# Security of sharepoint 365 list data sourcing Power Bi Report

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, sharepoint-online

I am working on a project where the source is a list in sharepoint 365. That List has security added to it. I'd like to understand if we can leverage that security in Power Bi. We know who the users connecting are in Power Bi. My vision is that the users will open the file and if they have access to the list then they would see the data. However, if they don't have access to the list then they would only see an empty file. In other words, is there a way to delegate the credentials from Power Bi to Sharepoint 365? Is that doable without adding further security to the workspace in Power Bi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Single-Sign On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-sso-overview) is not available for SharePoint because SharePoint doesn't support DirectQuery.  Data is always imported.